# Freeing C variables in Golang?

Tags: c, go, cgo

I'm confused about which variables need to be freed if I'm using C variables in Go.

For example, if I do this:

```
    s := C.CString(`something`)
```

Is that memory now allocated until I call `C.free(unsafe.Pointer(s))`, or is that OK to be garbage collected by Go when the function ends?

Or is it only variables that are created from the imported C code that need to be freed, and these C variables created from the Go code will be garbage collected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation does mention](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/):

```
// Go string to C string
// The C string is allocated in the C heap using malloc.
// It is the caller's responsibility to arrange for it to be
// freed, such as by calling C.free (be sure to include stdlib.h
// if C.free is needed).
func C.CString(string) *C.char
```

The [wiki shows an example](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/cgo):

```
package cgoexample

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myprint(char* s) {
        printf("%s", s);
}
*/
import "C"

import "unsafe"

func Example() {
        cs := C.CString("Hello from stdio\n")
        C.myprint(cs)
        C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
}
```

---

The article "[C? Go? Cgo!](http://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo)" shows that you don't need to free C numeric types:

```
func Random() int {
    var r C.long = C.random()
    return int(r)
}
```

But you would for string:

```
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func Print(s string) {
    cs := C.CString(s)
    C.fputs(cs, (*C.FILE)(C.stdout))
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
}
```

Comment: Does the same apply to *all* variables converted into C variables? Like `v := C.l_int32(123)`?

Comment: Or `var conf C.l_float32`

Comment: @Alasdair I didn't know about `C.l_xxx`, only `C.xxx`, but for numeric type, you wouldn't need to free the memory. I have edited the answer with a link to an article including examples.

Comment: l_xxx is used by Leptonica library for some reason. I'm not sure what the difference is, but Go happily creates these types and Leptonica happily accepts them.

Comment: @Alasdair `l_xxx` are just typedefs for normal number types, like if you'd do `type LUint64 uint64` in Go.